# How does the view "without mathematics no true wisdom is possible" imply an oligarchy? (History of Western Philosophy)

Tags: bertrand-russell, politics

In his chapter on Plato, Russell says "He was sufficiently Pythagorean to think that without mathematics no true wisdom is possible. This implies an oligarchy." and I can't follow the argument behind that implication. Where does it come from and is it tied to Russell's own time period?

Comment: It implies oligarchy in the sense that true wisdom is the exclusive domain of mathematicians.

Comment: wouldnt the mathmatics required for "wisdom" be considered basics by today's standards and thereby enabling almost everyone to govern wisely?

Comment: I wonder if he is talking not about earthly governments, but rather the ruling of truth by ways of thinking. Where only the paradigms that include mathematics can govern truth. Just a speculation. Otherwise how would one form of wisdom imply more or less numbers of capable rulers? Just the opposite makes sense (as your response comment suggests): democratizing wisdom by the spread of mathematics

Comment: Ask an average citizen today to demonstrate the Pythagorean theorem. More saliently, "*the  typical citizen  drops down to a lower level of mental performance as soon  as he enters the political field. He argues and analyzes  in  a  way which  he  would  readily  recognize  as  infantile within  the  sphere  of his real  interests*", Schumpeter. See [Voter ignorance and the democratic ideal](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/08913819808443511). Nonetheless, Plato's "rule of the wise" still proved to be worse historically.